# Can't open PDF document

Tags: 2007, pdf

I am able to open a PDF document that is uploaded on staging but not able to open same document from development server.

Its all working on IE but not on Chrome browser, I wonder if its related to SharePoint at all ?

I googled already and tried common things need to open PDF documents in chrome but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled one of custom webpart on that site and it started working, not sure what was the real issue as I have tried almost everything in above question and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your computer and try opening the PDF again
2. Open a local copy of a PDF in the web browser
3. Download the PDF again
4. Delete temporary Internet files
5. Deselect and then reselect the Display PDF In Browser preference
6. Try a different website
7. Install the latest version of Reader or Acrobat
8. Remove multiple versions of Reader or Acrobat, and then reinstall
9. View the PDF in a 32-bit version of the web browser

Source: http://www.techyv.com/questions/there-was-error-opening-document-access-denied